# Как получить status code в undetected_chromedriver

Tags: python, http

У меня проблема. Я использую undetected_chromedriver для запроса на сайт с cloudflare. Я искал но так и не нашел как получить status code( http response code ). Подскажите как его получить.

Мой код:

```
import undetected_chromedriver
from selenium import webdriver


url = ''

def init_webdriver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome(options)

    driver.get(url)

    # driver.save_screenshot('test.png')
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
try:
    init_webdriver()
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--deny-permission-prompts')
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")  
options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
driver = uc.Chrome(headless=True, use_subprocess=False, options=options, version_main=108, desired_capabilities=caps)

url = f"https://example.com"
driver.get(url)

def status_code_first_request(performance_log):

    for line in performance_log:
        try:
            json_log = json.loads(line['message'])
            if json_log['message']['method'] == 'Network.responseReceived':
                return json_log['message']['params']['response']['status']
        except:
            pass

status_code = status_code_first_request(performance_log) status_code
print(status_code)
```

Включить лог Selenium  `perfomance`

```py
caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]